# Finding the maximal `t` at which `u[x,t] == 1`?

Tags: mathematical-optimization

Given the smooth function `u[x,t]` on a domain, how do I find the maximal `t` at which `u[x,t] == 1` (leaving `x` unconstrained)?

I can plot the level curve with

```
ContourPlot[ u[x,t] == 1, {x, -50, -58}, {t, 50, 58} ]
```

but I'm not sure how to numerically locate the point I want.

Edit: My `u` is the solution to a PDE:

```
sol = NDSolve[
      { D[u[x, t], t] == D[u[x, t], x, x] 
          + D[u[x, t], x] - u[x, t]^3
          + 3 u[x, t]^2 -2 u[x, t],
        u[x, 0] == 3 Exp[-x^2 /6],
        u[-100, t] == 0,
        u[30, t] == 0 },
        u, {x, -100, 30}, {t, 0, 100}]
```

The point of interest lies in the domain $-58<x<-50$ and $50<t<58$.

Comment: It would be very useful to have your `u[x,t]`.

Comment: Done. But what difference does it make?

Comment: Try answering any new question without that information and maybe you'll see.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Before any real answer appears:

```
ContourPlot[Evaluate[u[x, t] /. sol] == 1, {x, -50, -58}, {t, 50, 58}
 ] //  Normal // Cases[#, Line[x__] :> x, Infinity][[ 1, ;; , 2]] & // Max
```

> ```
> 56.0628
> ```

...and the real answer:

```
U = u /. sol[[ 1]]

FindRoot[{U[x, t] == 1, D[U[x, t], x] == 0}, {{x, -56}, {t, 54}}]
```

> ```
> {x -> -56.0326, t -> 56.0635}
> ```

So graphical method was not so bad. :)

Comment: And it's even better than `NMaximize[{t, sol[x, t] == 1, -58 <= x <= 50, 50 <= t <= 58}, {x, t}]`.

Comment: @b.gatessucks Why do you think so?

Comment: @belisarius Kuba gets 56.0635, I get 56.0632.

Comment: @b.gatessucks I get `56.0635` using `NMaximize`, MMa 9.0

Answer (score 10):

Following the trend of posting alternative methods and skipping the obvious
`NMaximize[{t, sol[x, t] == 1, -58 <= x <= 50, 50 <= t <= 58}, {x, t}]`

```
max = SortBy[PixelValuePositions[
        i = Binarize@Image[ContourPlot[s[x, t] == 1, {x, -50, -58}, {t, 50, 58}, 
               Frame -> False, PlotRangePadding -> None], ImageSize->2500], Min], -#[[2]] &][[1, 2]]

N@Rescale[max, {1, ImageDimensions[i][[2]]}, {50, 58}]
(*
 56.0632
*)
```

Some precision is scarified to get errr ... whatever

Comment: Nice paralypsis there.

Comment: @YvesKlett I was waiting for someone to notice it :)

Comment: I shall call you Cicero henceforth :D

Comment: I learnt a new word! http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/paraleipsis#English